# Navbar scrolling to fixed top fine working But when browser reloading time scrolling navbar fixed not working useing bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fixed

bootstrap 4 Navbar scrolling to fixed top Working But when Browser reloading time same times mouse scrolling Navbar fixed not working. why not working i'm not understand?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section2">Exam Notic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section3">Student List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want your navbar to stay fixed to the top of the window when you scroll down like in [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/)?

Comment: @dutchess  I'm use navbar fixed to top working fine but when browser reloading time navbar fixed not working check now   https://codepen.io/imranhosen_me/pen/agBXVQ

Comment: That codepen seems to be working fine for me. I've run it full-screen, scrolled down and reloaded the frame, and the navbar is fixed to the top where it should be, and moving down when I scroll back to the top of the page. What is happening for you and what are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks @dutchess . When browser not reloading fine working bootstrap fixed navbar see image http://prntscr.com/o5m0do  Fine fixed http://prntscr.com/o5m273  . But when browser reloading time Mouse Scrolling not fixed navbar see http://prntscr.com/o5m1wr   My Expect Reloaded time Mouse scrolling Fixed Navbar working.  Codepen and this site same Code.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshots. I also had a look at the website (study.hopeitltd.com). The navbar only seems to 'disappear' whilst the page is reloading, and reappears when the reload is done. Please could you confirm this?